# Is using per-project venv considered a good practice in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, local, python-venv, pep

I'm pretty new to python development and trying to understand a sort of "pythonic way" of project development. I found the following PEPs:

1. [PEP370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/) (`.local` site-packages) which provides a way to do per-user package installation avoiding core site-packages pollution
2. [PEP405](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/) (`venv`) which by contrast provides a way to create a fully-isolated python environment. The PEP explicitly states that

> PEP 370 user-level site-packages are considered part of the system
>   site-packages for `venv` purposes: they are not available from an
>   isolated `venv`, but are available from an `include-system-site-packages = true` venv.

So `venv` is even isolated from `.local` site-packages.

Now I'm currently supporting two different projects that uses different versions of `apache-airflow`. So I'd like to have `IDE` support for different airflow versions using on each of these projects.

---

Does it even make sense to install `apache airflow` used in one of these projects into a `.local` packages? I would say no, so currently I'd prefer to create 2 different per-project `venv`s. Then the following question arises: When should we even prefer installation into a per-user `.local` site-packages to installation into a dedicated `venv`?

I'm on Ubuntu and some of packages came from `apt` install their dependencies into the core site-packages which we probably cannot control and make them to be installed into `.local` site packages. Like `protobuf` which tons of software depends on:

```
$ sudo aptitude why python3-protobuf                                                                                                                                                                                                   
i   gnome-session          Depends    gnome-shell (>= 3.25.91-0ubuntu4~)                                                                                                                                                                                      
i A gnome-shell            Recommends gnome-control-center                                                                                                                                                                                                    
i A gnome-control-center   Recommends gnome-online-accounts (>= 3.25.3)                                                                                                                                                                                       
i A gnome-online-accounts  Depends    python3-macaroonbakery                                                                                                                                                                                                  
i A python3-macaroonbakery Depends    python3-protobuf (>= 3.0.0)
```

Comment: For development, and also production in almost all cases, isolated virtualenvs are the way to go. I prefer virtualenvwrapper but newer tools are newer... You don't want to rely on your OSs version of packages since that will prevent you from upgrading to the latest version if that becomes a need. I've never found a use for per-user installs (but that doesn't mean they can't be useful).

Comment: (This question is opinion based, which is kind of against the rules of this site...) From my point of view there is never need for _local installations_ (neither _global_ actually), they kind of make sense for applications but it is much better solved with tools such as [pipx](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/), [shiv](https://pypi.org/project/shiv/), [pex](https://pypi.org/project/pex/), and so on. For development then virtual environments are definitely the way to go. Don't ever use the Python libraries installed via the operating system's package manager for your own developments.